# How to print Facebook style timestamps in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have a datetime that represents an event creation time and I need to show how much time has passed since then.

Examples: “right now”, “2 days ago”, “3 months from now”.

I know of [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/) for Java, but I need something for Django.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Py-Pretty](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-pretty/1) should do the trick... It also has support for future events as well.

Comment: I guess this is as close as it gets. I'll probably write a custom Django filter using Py-Pretty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for, but Django does have a built in template filter that achieves something similar: [timesince](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince)

> Formats a date as the time since that date (e.g., "4 days, 6 hours").
>
> Takes an optional argument that is a variable containing the date to use as the comparison point (without the argument, the comparison point is now). For example, if `blog_date` is a date instance representing midnight on 1 June 2006, and `comment_date is a date instance for 08:00 on 1 June 2006, then` {{ blog_date|timesince:comment_date }}` would return "8 hours".

Comment: It looks good for starting out, but it doesn't print the way I want to. For example it doesn't print the 'ago', and also it prints '0 minutes' instead of 'now'.

Comment: well it doesnt need to print 'ago'. In fact, that would actually break some of the core philosophies behind Django. You are supposed put the 'ago' in as a part of your template, like `user commented {{comment.date|timesince}} ago`.

Comment: And I guess you could have now by just having a simple if statement? Is that too much overkill?

Comment: Actually it's not, but I would find a filter doing that much cleaner and reusable. Why do you think it would break Django philosophies?

Comment: Django, amongst other MVC frameworks, is all about seperating the presentation from the logic. Well the filter isn't that clean and reusable if it is using a specific english word for appearance. Lets say you want to change 'ago' to 'in the past' so it read '3 minutes *in the past*'. Now, where would be the most logical place to go looking for where to make this change? In the .py file containing the logic for the template filter, or the .html template containing the presentation?